# highlight the selected line in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with content and another div with button. When I specify the line number from the second div, the cursor goes to the specific line number or position of the div with content. i want to highlight the whole line when the cursor moves to that line number. Is there any way.
This is what I have done so far

```
function scrollpage(){
  //Get the value of input text
  var lineNumber = document.getElementById("scrolltoposition").value;

  //Get the height of div and find the height of each lines
  var divHeight = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight
  var lineHeight =parseInt(document.getElementById('content').style.lineHeight);
  var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;
  var heightOfEachLine = divHeight/lines;

  //Finds the position of line number and scrolls to the line number
  var linePosition = Math.round(heightOfEachLine*lineNumber);
  window.scrollTo(0,linePosition);
}
```

This is the HTML part

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true" style ="background: 
    url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);
    background-attachment: local;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-color:#ccc;
    line-height:16px;">

    The content goes here

</div>
<div id="scroll">
    <input type="text" name="scrolltoposition" id="scrolltoposition">
    <button type="submit" onClick="scrollpage()">Go to</button>
</div>
```

The snippet is also included here

```js
function scrollpage(){
  var lineNumber = document.getElementById("scrolltoposition").value;
  var divHeight = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight
  var lineHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('content').style.lineHeight);
  var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;
  var heightOfEachLine = divHeight/lines;

  var linePosition = Math.round(heightOfEachLine*lineNumber);

  window.scrollTo(0,linePosition);
}
```

```html
 <div id="content" contenteditable="true" style ="background: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);
     background-attachment: local;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding-left: 35px;
     padding-top: 10px;
     border-color:#ccc;
     line-height:16px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Dabof nedalyhif dof ruh quy dyqueh ferabado fecy, jejotoe febalab quoel vitaquej, linol mi ledu. Balif dimilyd lalide fy fabitedoej, le lahalibese foebudeb nil, quebev boebil lu lelit datedive. Lelop tibed bab ni loesyj lo lerem, tyteloh puf, fecebide. Ra mobu vemilip desumesi lirebafuje bibec quide ni faj, lemym.<br />
    <br />
    Meca ni bol lev voedoenoso daqu, daju baquedysije, ni loenepelom cid quad vem. Faloe myli mifipe, foedem, maqu lamabelej, bade byqual jibaquy diped, mefa le. Be lef ly monile fu haben poep na delamyquoe debade ceby bodu vuvi nojyn. Quy, bit badipab dem be lede lilafim pululy helopeba hydede bal. Dami malytude moed, le lequ cem lalo teboba ve doedib, dib cef, ta.<br />
    <br />
    Tiruh boelehehi lijodi hap lide, hoedydin cava be febe ni hoebyboe babol lil. Que pedoepaquav moejoela mev, date caquylebin, jelit lalile fysebetob nifin lihum mipa vafemo, bec. Celeh, linul fud de, jevib fede liquo des dun hifamomife. Divim tusoemejele neduj bipolavifa le lon mije lod boset leroelebibi je. Firisec mum jilelanulo femaquojero lop mibodicoe dec bib moedafesol, so hutiquiqu.<br />
    <br />
    Lyd te bi pap saleli sabi mebebu qua, bat dilefu quab. Pi dide fi cinoed bu bobar leloele rale delele, pi lad. Tumedad fac fajyl da re te bel jaledoepyv jyloel ned, voevedoequi, vafadih re pac. Hidesela va bavoeca bisucoelele nalaban seladar loeval noti decelemyfe de najodedo. Lam da lalyfif davilal diqu, bi luco nedomolasoe que moemim.
</div>
            
<div id="scroll">
    <input type="text" name="scrolltoposition" id="scrolltoposition" />
    <button type="submit" onClick="scrollpage()">Go to</button>
</div>
```

What I want is when you select line 10, it goes to line 20 and the whole line should be highlighted. Can you help with that guys?

Comment: You can try with a semi transparent div on the line you want to highlight. You already have the position you want to go to, the height and the width of that div.

Comment: Gave this a shot and it seems to work for now: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7xm4Lr5n/

Comment: Thanks mate, it is working. Much appreciated